# wordpress memory size fetal error on functions.php

Tags: php, string, wordpress, serialization

I making a plugin for wordpress, but i have problem with allowed memory size  on my server, it is 128, they dont allow me to increase memory at run time.

my plugin have function to export user datas to csv and email to user. i getting fetal error on this wordpress, functions.php line 252

is there efficient way to optimize this below function to prevent getting error

thank you

```
function is_serialized( $data ) {
        // if it isn't a string, it isn't serialized
        if ( ! is_string( $data ) )
            return false;
        $data = trim( $data );
        if ( 'N;' == $data )
            return true;
        $length = strlen( $data );
        if ( $length < 4 )
            return false;
        if ( ':' !== $data[1] )
            return false;
        $lastc = $data[$length-1];
        if ( ';' !== $lastc && '}' !== $lastc )
            return false;
        $token = $data[0];
        switch ( $token ) {
            case 's' :
                if ( '"' !== $data[$length-2] )
                    return false;
            case 'a' :
            case 'O' :
                return (bool) preg_match( "/^{$token}:[0-9]+:/s", $data );
            case 'b' :
            case 'i' :
            case 'd' :
                return (bool) preg_match( "/^{$token}:[0-9.E-]+;\$/", $data );
        }
        return false;
    }
```

my function - fileds are dynamic getting from admin panel

```
$outFile = '';
                $blogusers = get_users();

                // retrieve the current options
                $spueIntervall = get_option('spue_intervall');
                //fileds are dynamic
                $spueSeperator = get_option('spue_seperator');
                $spueFields = get_option('spue_fields');

                // Check if the functions is already loaded
                if (!function_exists('get_userdata'))
                    require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');

                // Setup the top-line of the file
                foreach ($spueFields AS $fieldKey => $fieldValue)
                {

                    if ($fieldValue == 1)
                    {

                        $outFile .= $fieldKey . $spueSeperator;

                    }

                }

                $outFile .= "\n";


                // Loop to all users
                foreach ($blogusers as $user) 
                {

                    // Get the userdate
                    $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);

                    // Only output the needed data
                    foreach ($spueFields AS $fieldKey => $fieldValue)
                    {

                        if ($fieldValue == 1)
                        {

                            $outFile .= '"' . $user_info->{$fieldKey} . '"' . $spueSeperator;

                        }

                    }

                    $outFile .= "\n";

                }           


                // Save 
                file_put_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '\spue-export.csv', utf8_encode($outFile));
```

Comment: put csv structure please

Comment: here i added(fields are dynamic)

Comment: have a efficient way for do this :)

Answer (score 1):

got it

```
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
                $data = array();
                foreach ($spueFields AS $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
                if ($fieldValue == 1)
                        {
                    $value = isset( $user->{$fieldKey} ) ? $user->{$fieldKey} : '';
                    $value = is_array( $value ) ? serialize( $value ) : $value;
                    $data[] = '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $value ) . '"';
$outFile.=implode( ',', $data ) . "\n";                 
                }
```